# How to access Active Directory using C++Builder?

Tags: c++, active-directory, c++builder

I need to get a list of user names from Active Directory using C++Builder. I know I could shell out to batch file and run the csvde.exe command but surely there is a nicer way using a library or something, right?  Are there any C++ libraries? (hopefully with examples?)
Many thanks!
-Dan

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the SDK API for AD? [Active Directory Service Interfaces Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772218%28VS.85%29.aspx). There are examples for most common operations at [Using Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746512%28VS.85%29.aspx)